# How to make sidebar to increase its full length?

Tags: javascript, xml, xul

I created a sidebar in xul, and I need to make it flexible like Firefox' history and bookmark sidebars. To do this I tried to apply flex='1' to  (broadcasterset, broadcaster, page, grid), but there is no change. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "flexibility" is achieved using the [`<splitter>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/splitter). For example:

```
<hbox>
  <iframe id="sidebar" type="content" width="300"/>
  <splitter id="splitter" collapse="before" state="open"/>
  <iframe id="browser" type="content" flex="1"/>
</hbox>
```

You have to remember to hide the splitter as well if you hide the sidebar.